# Randomize the scalars of an array

Tags: code-golf, random

You must fill an array with every number from `0-n` inclusive. No numbers should repeat. However they must be in a random order.

## Rules

All standard [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules and standard loopholes are banned

The array must be generated pseudo-randomly. Every possible permutation should have a equal probability.

## Input

`n` in any way allowed in the I/O post on meta.

## Output

The array of numbers scrambled from `0-n` inclusive.

Comment: the output can be separated by newlines?

Comment: @Riley opps that was meant to be gone sorry.

Comment: @DrnglVrgs yes it can

Comment: By "numbers" I assume you mean "integers"?

Comment: Does it have to be an array, or is a list also acceptable?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen if a array is not possible (ahem python) then lists are fine. They are basically the same :P

Comment: @2EZ4RTZ And if an array is possible, but longer than using a List? ;)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen IMO lists = array but with searching support. So sure use a list

Answer (score 9):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org), 14 bytes

```perl6
{pick *,0..$_}
```

[Try it](https://tio.run/nexus/perl6#Ky1OVSgz00u25sqtVFBLzk9JVbD9X12QmZytoKVjoKenEl/7vzixUgEsY/r/a16@bnJickYqAA)

### Expanded:

```perl6
{           # bare block lambda with implicit parameter ｢$_｣

  pick      # choose randomly without repeats
    *,      # Whatever (all)
    0 .. $_ # Range from 0, to the input (inclusive)
}
```

Answer (score 8):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 3 bytes

```
Ý.r
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@394rl7R//@WX/PydZMTkzNSAQ)

```
Ý   # Make a list from 0 to input
 .r # Shuffle it randomly
```

Answer (score 8):

## Pyth, 3 bytes

```
.Sh
```

[Demonstration](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=.Sh&input=10&debug=0)

`.S` is shuffle. It implicitly casts an input integer `n` to the range `[0, 1, ..., n-1]`. `h` is `+1`, and the input is taken implicitly.

Answer (score 7):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 16 bytes

```r
sample(0:scan())
```

reads from `stdin`. `sample` randomly samples from the input vector, returning a (pseudo)random sequence.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/r#@1@cmFuQk6phYFWcnJinoan539DgPwA)

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 bytes

```
0rẊ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@29Q9HBX1////02/5uXrJicmZ6QCAA)

**Explanaion:**

```
0rẊ 
0r  Inclusive range 0 to input.
  Ẋ Shuffle.
    Implicit print.
```

### Alternate solution, 3 bytes

```
‘ḶẊ
```

**Explanation:**

```
‘ḶẊ
‘   Input +1
 Ḷ  Range 0 to argument.
  Ẋ Shuffle.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@/@oYcbDHdse7ur6//@/6de8fN3kxOSMVAA)

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 51 bytes

```python
lambda n:sample(range(n+1),n+1)
from random import*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#S7ON@Z@TmJuUkqiQZ1WcmFuQk6pRlJiXnqqRp22oqQMiuNKK8nMVgIIpQCoztyC/qETrf0FRZl6JQpqGqSYXjGlogMQ21fz/NS9fNzkxOSMVAA)

There is `random.shuffle()` but it modifies the argument in place instead of returning it...

Comment: You [can](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4942/66833) use `random.shuffle`

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing Yeah, but that wouldn't work. For example, `lambda n:shuffle(range(n+1))` wouldn't write the output anywhere.

Answer (score 5):

## PHP, 42 Bytes

```php
$r=range(0,$argn);shuffle($r);print_r($r);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/php#s7EvyCjgUkksSs@zNTQwsP6vUmRblJiXnqphoAMW1bQuzihNS8tJ1VAp0rQuKMrMK4kvArP//wcA)

Answer (score 5):

## Bash, <s>18</s> 11 bytes

```
shuf -i0-$1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/vzijNE1BN9NAV8Xw////hgYA)

Comment: If newlines are allowed we can forget the echo part

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 4 bytes

```
ò öx
```

[Try it online](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.4&code=8iD2eA==&input=NQ==)

---

```
    :Implicit input of integer U
ò   :Generate array of 0 to U.
öx  :Generate random permutation of array.
    :Implicit output of result.
```

Comment: Gosh darn it, I thought `öx` would be enough until I noticed the "inclusive" part. (You could replace the `x` with almost anything else, btw)

Comment: @ETHproductions, that was my first thought too.

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 4 bytes

```
QZ@q
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@x8Y5VD4/7@hwde8fN3kxOSMVAA)

#### Explanation

```
Q     % Implicitly input n. Add 1
Z@    % Random permutation of [1 2 ... n+1]
q     % Subtract 1, element-wise. Implicitly display
```

Answer (score 3):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), <s>7</s> 6 bytes

*1 byte removed thanks to [Erik the Outgolfer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/41024/erik-the-outgolfer).*

```
{),mr}
```

This is an anonymous block (function) that takes an integer from the stack and replaces it with the result. **[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cjam#K8pUgIBUZYWg1MQUhcy8ktT01KL/1Zo6uUW1/@sKEPKuFanJyaUlqQpJOfnJ2XoKwSVFmXnpCkWpBUWpxal5JYklmfl5CvlpQJHi0pyS/6Zf8/J1kxOTM1IB)**

#### Explanation

```
{     e# Begin block
)     e# Increment: n+1
,     e# Range: [0 1 ... n]
mr    e# Shuffle
}     e# End block
```

Comment: Isn't `{),mr}` 1 byte shorter?

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Indeed! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica, 24 bytes

```
RandomSample@Range[0,#]&
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 2 bytes

```
⟦ṣ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brachylog2#@/9o/rKHOxf//29o/D/qa16@bnJickYqAA)

#### Explanation

```
⟦     Range from 0 to Input
 ṣ    Shuffle
```

Answer (score 3):

## C#, 76 bytes

```
using System.Linq;i=>new int[i+1].Select(x=>i--).OrderBy(x=>Guid.NewGuid());
```

This returns an IOrderedEnumerable, I hope that's okay, or else I need a few more bytes for a .ToArray()

Answer (score 3):

## Java 8, <s>114</s> <s>111</s> 97 bytes

```java
import java.util.*;n->{List l=new Stack();for(;n>=0;l.add(n--));Collections.shuffle(l);return l;}
```

-3 bytes and bug-fixed thanks to *@OlivierGrégoire*.
-4 bytes thanks to *@Jakob*.
-10 bytes by removing `.toArray()`.

**Explanation:**

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##nY69bsMwDIR3PwVHqYAUdwg6CM6StQ0KeCw6KLLcyJEpQ6JSBIGf3VV@xnYpQA68O@K7QZ@0CJPFoTsubpxCJBiKJjM5L58UAKxW8K6LHHqgg4X9mawwISNVlfE6JXjTDi8VgEOysdfGwu56Ary6RGBY0QG5KtJctkwiTc7ADhAaWFBsLrekb9B@Q0vaHBlXfYhM4aaplZe66xgKwbnaBu@tIRcwyXTIfe8t81xFSzkieDUv6s6Y8t4XxgN1Cq6DsfRkLUWHXx@foPm9ZHtOZEcZMsmpWOSRoTTsuea3yr8G/naury/rf7@u6wd2rublBw)

```java
import java.util.*;        // Required import for List, Stack and Collections
n->{                       // Method with integer parameter and Object-array return-type
  List l=new Stack();      //  Initialize a List
  for(;n>=0;l.add(n--));   //  Loop to fill the list with 0 through `n`
  Collections.shuffle(l);  //  Randomly shuffle the List
  return l;                //  Convert the List to an Object-array and return it
}                          // End of method
```

Comment: Bug: doesn't include `n`. Fix and golf: `for(n++;--n>=0;l.add(n));`. Also, I say you don't need to return an array. Array and list are the same in most language, so just return the list.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Woops.. That's what you get for not checking properly and just posting.. Thanks for the bug-fix (and 4 bytes saved in the process).

Comment: Well, three actually, because I edited again, having myself introduced another bug: `>` should be `>=`.

Comment: -4 bytes: use a `Stack` instead of a `Vector` and change your loop to `for(;n>=0;l.add(n--));`. And returning a `java.util.List` is definitely fine.

Answer (score 2):

## [Ohm](https://github.com/MiningPotatoes/Ohm), 2 bytes

```
#╟
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/ohm#@6/8aOr8//8tAQ)

Comment: [This](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw4yHO7Y93NX1//9/0695@brJickZqQA) is a better link.

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, 4 Bytes

```
.S}0
```

[Try it here!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=.S%7D0&input=5&debug=0)

Comment: You can golf to 3 bytes. `.S` with an integer argument is the same as `.SU`, and `[0..n]` can be coded as `Uh`, so you can use `.SUh`, which then becomes `.Sh`.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer thanks for the hint, but as someone has alread posted the solution you propose I will leave this as this.

Comment: Well, it's borderline whether that should've been a separate answer or not, but I believe it counts as a dupe, so even it being allowed, I'd consider it just builtin substitution, so nah, I didn't want to post separate, but isaacg did.

Answer (score 2):

## C, 75 bytes

```
a[99],z,y;f(n){if(n){a[n]=--n;f(n);z=a[n];a[n]=a[y=rand()%(n+1)];a[y]=z;}}
```

Recursive function that initializes from the array's end on the way in, and swaps with a random element before it on the way out.

Comment: What if `n > 98`?

Comment: It would fail, of course, but input range wasn't specified in the problem.  Please don't make me malloc :)

Comment: change `a` into a para to fit the rule more?

Comment: [67 bytes](https://tio.run/##HYuxCsMgFEX3fMUlEFCikCVDaiUfIg5isDj0tUiXKPbXrel04ZxzvXx435oz22ZFFqcKjHih3RmyWkoSWTtz6uToYJfi05es6MjqKxH/Lt8WVdvTRWK8BLZyNYRXYoj0QdSLQsQda595BkcZgHfqLjCM04FRwJlo0V@1th8 "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, 20 bytes

`->n{[*0..n].shuffle}`

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 33 bytes

```
Ａ…·⁰ＮβＦβ«ＡβδＡ‽δθＰＩθ↓Ａ⟦⟧βＦδ¿⁻θκ⊞βκ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/charcoal#TY27DoIwFIZneYoznpOUxMVFJ6MLA8a4Ggd6ARugJbTFwfjstaAmjv/lyxf3zunGYGFEF5ye1KUyjcI1g8IMwZ9Cz9WIRAw47bLajoCc4JmtvhxnINPwi4mWtkeZ/mKuy9B5PYzaeDxUzqOgpbWTwu3RPswfer19HKtFIgl0DVhqExwKBi0RnIO7z8I2vV4xbmI@xdx1bw) Link is to verbose version of code.

Apparently it takes 17 bytes to remove an element from a list in Charcoal.

Edit: These days it only takes three bytes, assuming you want to remove all occurrences of the item from the list. This plus other Charcoal changes cut the answer down to 21 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYw9C8IwFADn9leETi@QgouTU8cuIrq6pEloAumr@aqD@NufKXY97k5ZGdUqPdGQkpsRRlS@JLeZu8TZwEmwEV8lX8symQicCxb4pX1b5w2DwNmnbY6yBnpdKhPMVqW5RYcZBq3BCtY9seM7PeRHmXKUKkPY7f/0S3SmfqM@@R8)

Comment: Yikes that is a lot

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 5 bytes

```apl
?⍨1+⊢
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qG@qp/@jtgkG/x2BpP2j3hWG2o@6Fv3/76hgCgA)

Assumes `⎕IO←0`, which is default on many machines.

#### Explanation

`⊢` the right argument

`1+` add 1 to it

`?⍨` generate numbers 0 .. `1+⊢`-1 and randomly deal them in an array so that no two numbers repeat

Answer (score 2):

## q/kdb+, 11 bytes

**Solution:**

```
{(0-x)?1+x}
```

**Example:**

```
q){(0-x)?1+x}10
5 9 7 1 2 4 8 0 3 10
q){(0-x)?1+x}10
6 10 2 8 4 5 9 0 7 3
q){(0-x)?1+x}10
9 6 4 1 10 8 2 7 0 5
```

**Explanation:**

Use the `?` [operator](http://code.kx.com/wiki/Reference/QuestionSymbol) with a negative input to give the full list of `0->n` without duplicates:

```
{(0-x)?1+x} / solution
{         } / lambda expression
         x  / implicit input
       1+   / add one
      ?     / rand
 (0-x)      / negate x, 'dont put item back in the bag'
```

Answer (score 2):

## TI-83 BASIC, 5 bytes (boring)

```
randIntNoRep(0,Ans
```

Yep, a builtin. `randIntNoRep(` is a two-byte token, and `Ans` is one byte.

#### More fun, 34 bytes:

```
Ans→N
seq(X,X,0,N→L₁
rand(N+1→L₂
SortA(L₂,L₁
L₁
```

Straight from [tibasicdev](http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/randintnorep). Probably golfable, but I haven't found anything yet.

What this does: Sorts a random array, moving elements of the second arg (`L₁` here) in the same way as their corresponding elements.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 51 bytes

```
n=>[...Array(n+1).keys()].sort(_=>.5-Math.random())
```

Comment: I don't think this is uniform; I've tried `f(5)` 10 times and `5` has been one of the last two items every time.

Comment: Just ran it again a couple of times myself and got `1,5,4,0,2,3` & `1,0,2,5,3,4`. EDIT: And a few more https://prnt.sc/fe0goe

Comment: Just ran a quick test which runs `f(5)` 1e5 times and finds the average position of each number in the results. The resulting array was `[ 1.42791, 1.43701, 2.00557, 2.6979, 3.3993, 4.03231 ]`, so I don't think it's uniform. ([code](https://pastebin.com/NZfAnXKd))

Comment: I think I have a 93 byte solution that could work.  `n=>(a=[...Array(n).keys(),n++]).reduce((a,v,i)=>([a[i],a[j]]=[a[j=n*Math.random()|0],v],a),a)`?

Comment: Sorting on the result of `random()` isn't uniform. See (for example) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BrowserChoice.eu#Criticism

Comment: @kamoroso94 Strictly speaking, shuffling using `n*` isn't uniform either, you need to use `i*` for a truly random shuffle.

Answer (score 1):

## [Aceto](https://github.com/aceto/aceto), <s>15</s> <s>14</s> 16 bytes

```
@lXp
Y!`n
zi&
0r
```

Push zero on the stack, read an integer, construct a range and shuffle it:

```
Y
zi
0r
```

Set a catch mark, test length for 0, and (in that case) exit:

```
@lX
 !`
```

Else print the value, a newline, and jump back to the length test:

```
   p
   n
  &
```

*(I had to change the code because I realized I misread the question and had constructed a range from 1-n, not 0-n.)*

Answer (score 1):

## [Go](https://golang.org/), 92 bytes

Mostly losing to the need to seed the PRNG.

```go
import(."fmt";."math/rand";."time")
func f(n int){Seed(Now().UnixNano());Println(Perm(n+1))}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/go#PY3BCsIwEETv/YqQ0y5itAdP/YdSED9gSRMbdDclRBRKP9tzTEWc05sZhpnJ3ujqFFOQEniOKYPRnrPujGbK0yGRjJvJgZ3Gxj/EKg@igmRczs6N0McnoLlIePUkERC7IdX2LjC4xCC7FnEt3@F2A7g0qsrDCX/QHv9Us7W8Je4t2cl9AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [8th](http://8th-dev.com/), <s>42</s> <s>36</s> 34 bytes

**Code**

```
>r [] ' a:push 0 r> loop a:shuffle
```

SED (Stack Effect Diagram) is `n -- a`

**Usage and example**

```
ok> 5 >r [] ' a:push 0 r> loop a:shuffle .
[2,5,0,3,1,4]
```

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript (ES6), 68 bytes

```
n=>[...Array(n+1)].map((n,i)=>[Math.random(),i]).sort().map(n=>n[1])
```

Creates an array of form

```
[[Math.random(), 0],
 [Math.random(), 1],
 [Math.random(), 2],...]
```

Then sorts it and returns the last elements in the new order

Answer (score 1):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 90 bytes

```
proc R n {lsort -c {try expr\ rand()>.5 on 9} [if [incr n -1]+2 {concat [R $n] [incr n]}]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0nO@f@/oCg/WSFIIU@hOqc4v6hEQTdZobqkqFIhtaKgKEahKDEvRUPTTs9UIT9PwbJWITozDYjzkouAGnQNY7WNFKqT8/OSE0sUooMUVPJiYZKxtbG1/wtKS4pB4kYGsf8B)

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 96 bytes

```
proc R n {proc f a\ b {expr rand()>.5}
set i -1
while \$i<$n {lappend L [incr i]}
lsort -c f $L}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0nO@f@/oCg/WSFIIU@hGsxKU0iMUUhSqE6tKChSKErMS9HQtNMzreUqTi1RyFTQNeQqz8jMSVWIUcm0UQHqyUksKEjNS1HwUYjOzEsuUsiMreXKKc4vKlHQBZml4lP7v6C0pFghOkjByCD2PwA)

Comment: Try to outgolf got the same byte count: https://tio.run/##DcmxCoMwFEbh3af4hwztoLSFbuITOLkaBxsDvXCJl5uUtkiePWY68J3kuBTR3WFCwBF9AqG9N983sYc11JvKvIr4sGHETMEpaMkNx10TWoejTv7XWLzgf6IWuobtch26Z84wYy7ySRHzhMdtKSc

Answer (score 1):

## J, 11 Bytes

```
(?@!A.i.)>:
```

#### Explanation:

```
         >:   | Increment
(?@!A.i.)     | Fork, (f g h) n is evaluated as (f n) g (h n)
      i.      | Integers in range [0,n) inclusive
 ?@!          | Random integer in the range [0, n!)
    A.        | Permute right argument according to left
```

Examples:

```
    0 A. i.>:5
0 1 2 3 4 5
    1 A. i.>:5
0 1 2 3 5 4
    (?@!A.i.)>: 5
2 3 5 1 0 4
    (?@!A.i.)>: 5
0 3 5 1 2 4
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript ES6, 60 bytes, uniform distribute

```js
f=n=>n?(z=f(n-1),z[n]=z[y=Math.random()*-~n|0],z[y]=n,z):[0]

s={};
for(i=0; i<1000; i++) k=f(2), s[k]=-~s[k];
for(i in s) console.log(i, s[i]);
```

Answer (score 1):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), <s>82</s> 80 bytes

```
{for(n=$1+2;++j<n;$j=j-1);for(srand();--n;){t=$(i=int(n*rand()+1));$i=$n;$n=t}}1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcsxCoAwDADAz2RIDB0qOMU8piBCK0SoBYfSt0fF@bh0H@59PyuaQuRZmMtqAkVLiCQfXDXZhiQhmFBvCpg1W0ObfuBIJJAV3mbaxojuywM)

`AWK` doesn't have a built-in shuffle, so this is the best I could come up with.

The `srand()` call is needed to prevent each execution from returning the same randomized sequence.

Thanks go to @ceilingcat for moving the call to *srand()* and the arithmetic tweaks to save 2 bytes.

Comment: @ceilingcat if we keep managing to shave off 2 bytes every 5 years, then in 200 years we'll have a 0-byte solution :-)

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 3 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
Ėµr
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPSVDNCU5NiVDMiVCNXImZm9vdGVyPSZpbnB1dD0xMCZmbGFncz0=)

##### Explanation

```python
Ėµr  # Implicit input
Ė    # Push [0..input]
 µr  # Random shuffle
     # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 25 bytes

```
[ dup [0,b] swap sample ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0tMLskv@h8a7OnnbqWQm1iSoVeUmJeeWqwApFLycxWyU4vyUnMUCopSS0oqC4oy80oUrLm4DA3@RyuklBYoRBvoJMUqFJcnFigUJ@YW5KQqxP5PTszJUdD7DwA)

```
        ! 10
dup     ! 10 10
[0,b]   ! 10 { 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 }
swap    ! { 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 } 10
sample  ! { 3 6 9 10 4 8 2 5 7 0 }
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 17 bytes

```
$=>[shuffle@0..&]
```

[Try it!](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?HiHnFm)

```
$=>[          ; a function where input is assigned to &
    0..&      ; a range from 0 to input inclusive
    @         ; reify the range (make it a concrete array)
    shuffle   ; shuffle it
]             ; end function
```

Answer (score 1):

## [RProgN 2](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/RProgN-2), 3 bytes

```
0Rñ
```

### Explained

```
0Rñ
0R  # Range of numbers 0-n (Implicit input)
  ñ # Shuffle, Implicit output.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Kyooyk/P0zX6/98g6PDG////mwIA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 21 bytes

```perl
@a{0..<>}=$,=$/;say%a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/98hsdpAT8/GrtZWRcdWRd@6OLFSNfH/f0PTf/kFJZn5ecX/dX1N9QwMDQA)